# Refresh the object detail page instead refreshing inline VF page when clicking on the inline VF Button

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, inline-visualforce, refresh

I use a VF Component and it's embedded in an inline Visualforce page. I have a button called 'Submit' in the Component. I want to refresh the whole Object record page instead the Visualforce page when I click on 'Submit'. I tried giving the following, adding onclick="top.location.reload(true);" but it seems not to be working. Any help on this would be appreciated!

```
<apex:commandButton value="{!$Label.Submit_Button}" action="{!saveRatings}" onclick="top.location.reload(true);" />
```

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that the `onclick` will take place before your controller's `action` method is called and your `saveRatings` method may or may not be executed - depending on how quickly the refresh takes place while the browser is attempting to POST the data to the controller. Take a look at questions like this one for suggestions: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/37036/660

Answer (score 1):

Please try using,

```
window.top.location.reload();
```

The main problem is that inline page will be in visualforce domain(eg ap1.visualforce.com) and main page will be in salesforce domain(eg ap1.salesforce.com). There are security restrictions regarding cross domain javascript.

Comment: Tried this but still seems not working !

Comment: Please check if developer mode is enabled. If it is enabled, please disable it and try.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible, the platform will prevent the VF component from altering the detail page.

I don't know the specifics of your component, but maybe a Javascript button on the detail page which calls your controller code would work (as that WILL be able to reload the record page).