# Getting cors error when trying to refresh parent page in an embedded VF page

Tags: visualforce, iframe

I was trying to refresh a page from an embedded VF page. Since it is an iframe in the big page, so I have tried:

```
window.parent.location.reload();
```

and

```
parent.location.href = parent.location.href;
```

For both of them, I got the same error message:

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "https://c.cs81.visual.force.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

It seems weird to me that I am getting a CORS error here. Is there a way I can walkaround this issue?

Comment: Did you try this ? - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/107623/refreshing-sfdc-page-from-vf-frame-cors-issue

Comment: @JitenderPadda Thank you. It works really well for me.