# How refresh parent sf page that has a vf page that is embedded in a layout

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a vf page embedded in a regular sf page layout. When the save method in the controller is done, I need to refresh the whole parent page not just the embedded vf page.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Where is your save button? Is it inside embedded vf page?

Comment: Yes it is embedded.

Comment: Check this link, I think it will help http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/37036/how-to-refresh-the-parent-page-after-a-save-action-in-a-visualforce-page-embedde

Comment: I tried it. I get an error "Unsupported attribute target"

Answer (score 1):

Well, after completion of Server side code you can call **oncomplete** to call any javascriipt for page processing. We can use this for our advantage.

**oncomplete="window.location.reload();"** to referesh the whole page.

in your VF page if you have used commandButton or anything similar.

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" id="theButton" oncomplete="Window.location.reload();"/>
```

Comment: Didn't do it. here is what I wrote     <apex:commandButton action="{!addTraining}" value="Save Changes" id="saveButton" oncomplete="Window.location.reload();" rerender="all"/>

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your scenario, You have given the VF Page in a Section of Detail Page in Layout of your record. In that VF Page, You are saving the Record, so want to reload automatically. If that is what you are seeking for, then follow the below steps.

In your Controller Class -> In the Constructor, Get the ID of the Record like

```
public APEXCONTROLLERCONSTRUCTOR(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    RecordId = controller.getId();
}
```

In your AddTraining method, call using the PageReference like below.

```
PageReference pg = new PageReference('/'+RecordId);
return pg;
```

It will reload the Page.

Hope this might helps...

Comment: This is the closest answer so far but it reloads the parent page in the embedded section and not the whole screen. How to achieve this?

Comment: Please try my updated answer.

Comment: Whole screen in the sense, I didn't get you... Please tell me clearly what you want to achieve...

Comment: This is showing promise but it keeps the parent page as it is and just puts a new parent page and the embedded vf page in the area on the page where the vf page was.  I need it to show like a regular sf page full screen not inside a layout section. Does that make sense?

Comment: So, You are saying that the Parent Page is getting in the VF Page Section?

Comment: The parent page is a SF record. I put vf page in a regular page layout section. When I click save in the vf page, the sub section where the vf page was now shows the parent page with the vf page in it. So I end up having a parent with its vf page inside a parent. It is as if the refresh code only knows of the smaller windows area and not of the full size windows that the original parent is.

Comment: can you please "put a screenshot of present result (or) Post your code" by updating the question. Otherwise it may leads you in the wrong way... By assuming on something, I cannot say you anything.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, this worked. Thank you all who have helped me with this.

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!addTraining}" value="Save Changes" id="saveButton" oncomplete="refreshPage();"/>

<script>

function refreshPage(){
    window.top.location.href =  '{!redirectUrl}';//define this in the controller
}
</script>
```